# Javascript hide and show on click not rendering and does not give me any errors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show and hide content using Javascript on-click function. I have a table that is quite long, so I used class display: "none" for the part of it. Then I added a button, clicking on which would display the rest of the table. Like a hide/show toggle. 
It does not render. what is the issue here? The console does not give me any errors. Thank you,

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("change");

    for (var i = 0; i != hidden.length; i++) {
    if (hidden[i].style.display === 'none') {
        hidden[i].style.display === 'visible';
    } else {
      hidden[i].style.display === 'none';
    }
}};
```

```css
#dates {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;

}

table {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 text-align: left;
}
tr td {
 border-top: 1px solid gray;
 margin: 5px 10px;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 1.3em;

}
th {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 10px;
}
.change {
 display: none;
}

#button {
 width: 25%;
 padding: 15px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title> Mystic Mind...</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="css/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website gallery.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<section class="holder" id="dates">
  <div>
    <header>Tour Dates</header>
       <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Location</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>August 5, 2018</td>
            <td>Parlour</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>June 22, 2018</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>May 4, 2018</td>
            <td>Rose In Rio</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>May 3, 2018</td>
            <td>AfterOffice @ Deltoro</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>April 18, 2018</td>
            <td>Rose In Rio</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>March 15, 2018</td>
            <td>Maldita Malta</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>March 2, 2018</td>
            <td>Vasily Zatek</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>December 1, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>November 11, 2017</td>
            <td>Buennanote</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>October 27, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>September 21, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>August 18, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>July 18, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>June 17, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>June 9, 2017</td>
            <td>Wildflower</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>June 2, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>April 6, 2017</td>
            <td>Escobar</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>March 10, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>March 4, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>March 2, 2017</td>
            <td>Wallen</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>February 2, 2017</td>
            <td>Wallen</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>January 26, 2017</td>
            <td>Escobar</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>January 20, 2017</td>
            <td>Wildflower</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
          <div id="button">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" onclick="myFunction()">Past Dates...</button>
          </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: `===` is an equality operator. `=` is the assignment operator. Probably worth reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: The js code in the top, you do not need the script tags. Script tags are used when you are introducing js in your HTML. Second: I think it should be `onclick="myFunction"` aka drop the parenthesis. Otherwise the functions gets evaluated right away and returns probly undefined, which is stored in your `onclick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in javascript

`hidden[i].style.display === 'none'` were always returning empty so instead you can use `element.className` which return **class** specified for that element

> So: `if(hidden[i].offsetWidth == 0 && hidden[i].offsetHeight == 0){}` this will return true if the element is present else false.

so the changes will be something as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button").querySelector('button');
    var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
    for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
      if (hidden[i].offsetWidth == 0 && hidden[i].offsetHeight == 0) {
        hidden[i].style.setProperty("display", "table-row", "important");
        button.innerHTML = 'Show less...';
      } else {
        hidden[i].style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
        button.innerHTML = 'Past Dates...';
      }
    }
};
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var button = document.getElementById("button").querySelector('button');
    var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
    for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
      if (hidden[i].offsetWidth == 0 && hidden[i].offsetHeight == 0) {
        hidden[i].style.setProperty("display", "table-row", "important");
        button.innerHTML = 'Show less...';
      } else {
        hidden[i].style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
        button.innerHTML = 'Past Dates...';
      }
    }
};
```

```css
#dates {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;

}

table {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 text-align: left;
}
tr td {
 border-top: 1px solid gray;
 margin: 5px 10px;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 1.3em;

}
th {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 10px;
}
.change {
 display: none;
}

#button {
 width: 25%;
 padding: 15px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title> Mystic Mind...</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="css/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website gallery.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<section class="holder" id="dates">
  <div>
    <header>Tour Dates</header>
       <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Location</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>August 5, 2018</td>
            <td>Parlour</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>June 22, 2018</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>May 4, 2018</td>
            <td>Rose In Rio</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>May 3, 2018</td>
            <td>AfterOffice @ Deltoro</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>April 18, 2018</td>
            <td>Rose In Rio</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>March 15, 2018</td>
            <td>Maldita Malta</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>March 2, 2018</td>
            <td>Vasily Zatek</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>December 1, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>November 11, 2017</td>
            <td>Buennanote</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>October 27, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>September 21, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>August 18, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>July 18, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>June 17, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>June 9, 2017</td>
            <td>Wildflower</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>June 2, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>April 6, 2017</td>
            <td>Escobar</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>March 10, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>March 4, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>March 2, 2017</td>
            <td>Wallen</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>February 2, 2017</td>
            <td>Wallen</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>January 26, 2017</td>
            <td>Escobar</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>January 20, 2017</td>
            <td>Wildflower</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
          <div id="button">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" onclick="myFunction()">Past Dates...</button>
          </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Thank you Vishal, this worked! what does not work is bringing the section back to its original state when clicking on button again. Once more information is shown, clicking on "show Less" button should switch the section to class "change"

Comment: it works exactly the way I wanted it to work. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a class `.change` that has the rule `display: none;` I suggest relying on the class rather than changing the style explicitly.
Here's a demo:

```js
  

    function myFunction() {
 var button = document.getElementById("button");
 var hidden = document.getElementsByClassName("change");
 for(var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
   hidden[i].classList.toggle('change' );
          // .toggle() instead of if and else
        }
}
```

```css
#dates {
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;

}

table {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 text-align: left;
}
tr td {
 border-top: 1px solid gray;
 margin: 5px 10px;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 1.3em;

}
th {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 10px;
}
.change {
 display: none;
}

#button {
 width: 25%;
 padding: 15px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title> Mystic Mind...</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lightbox.min.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="css/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website gallery.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



</head>

<section class="holder" id="dates">
  <div>
    <header>Tour Dates</header>
       <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Venue</th>
            <th>Location</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>August 5, 2018</td>
            <td>Parlour</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>June 22, 2018</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>May 4, 2018</td>
            <td>Rose In Rio</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>May 3, 2018</td>
            <td>AfterOffice @ Deltoro</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>April 18, 2018</td>
            <td>Rose In Rio</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>March 15, 2018</td>
            <td>Maldita Malta</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>March 2, 2018</td>
            <td>Vasily Zatek</td>
            <td>Buenos Aires, Argentina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>December 1, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>November 11, 2017</td>
            <td>Buennanote</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>October 27, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>September 21, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>August 18, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>July 18, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>June 17, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>June 9, 2017</td>
            <td>Wildflower</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>June 2, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>April 6, 2017</td>
            <td>Escobar</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>March 10, 2017</td>
            <td>One Loft</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>March 4, 2017</td>
            <td>Parlor</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>March 2, 2017</td>
            <td>Wallen</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>February 2, 2017</td>
            <td>Wallen</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="change">
            <td>January 26, 2017</td>
            <td>Escobar</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
           <tr class="change">
            <td>January 20, 2017</td>
            <td>Wildflower</td>
            <td>Toronto, Canada</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
          <div id="button">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary waves-effect" onclick="myFunction()">Past Dates...</button>
          </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: This worked as well! although when I click on "Show More" button, it does not toggle to original state (with class display: "none"...) Thank you :)